# Calling Sass function from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

Earlier my question was:-

I have the following code in my Sass file

```
.random {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1;

    &:before {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 0.2em;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-right: 0.4em  solid transparent;
        border-left: 0.4em solid transparent;
        content: "";
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }
}

.perc-neg:before {
    border-top: 0.5em solid #FCB062;
}

.perc-neg.good:before {
    border-top: 0.5em solid #98F1AC;
}
```

I have a div with 
         class = "random perc-neg good"

Now I want to change style of the above div. how to do it?

I tried following in console but it returns empty object

```
$("random perc-neg good:before").css("color","red");
$("random.perc-neg.good:before").css("color","red");
$(".random.perc-neg.good:before").css("color","red");
```

Someone has suggested its a possible duplicate but its not.

Int he related question, the user just wanted to make it visible or hidden so two classes will be sufficient.

But my requirement is to change the color as per user's choice which he can select from wide range of colors.

Its definitely impossible to define a class with each color changes.

And we cant pass some variable to css as well to change the color property accordingly.

**Updated Question:**

I am now using Sass.
I have defined an function to update the color

```
@function em($color) {
  @return border-bottom: 0.5em solid $color;
 }

.perc-neg.good:before {
    em(#98F1AC);
}
```

definitely, I can call the function from the Sass file but how to call it from javascript

Now I want to pass the hex code of color from javascript

I need to pass something like this from javascript

```
.perc-neg.good:before(#98F1AC)
```

looked for the same in google did not find anything relevant
Instead of marking it as duplicate, it would be much better if you can provide a solution

Comment: Can you show us also the [tag:html]?

Comment: can set the text of a style tag

Comment: @ charlietfl can you please bit more specific

Comment: I used less css but how to call the css function from my javascript? I have updated my question. Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the style of `pseudo` elements  are **not** possible because `:after` and `:before` are not part of the DOM technically. You need to find a work around or use additional classes to achieve this.

Comment: updated my question as why i cant i use additional classes. can you please have a look into it

Answer (score 0):

You can use less library which allows you to render css at run time here is a [reference](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser).

**#Updated Answer**

You can try doing something like this:

```
.perc-neg.good:before {
    border-color: @BorderColor;
}
```

and call this method whenever you want to update the css like this:

```
less.modifyVars({
  '@BorderColor': '#5B83AD'
});
```

Comment: I used less css but how to call the css function from my javascript?
I have updated my question. Do you have any idea how to achieve this?